# What kind of political institutions existed in Sakai, Japan in the 500s and 600s AD?

Tags: japan, medieval-japan

What government bodies were elected and by whom in Sakai Japan during the 500s and 600s AD?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I had already read wikipedia Mark. I have refined the question with specific dates.

Comment: @TylerDurden During the 500s, my understanding is that Sakai had some kind of likely oligarchical but formal elections or assemblies. Wikipedia says this, this source says it https://books.google.com/books?id=z8Flb0gZ3ZkC&pg=SA7-PA10&lpg=SA7-PA10&dq=elections+in+medieval+sakai&source=bl&ots=NMj5pIH0gj&sig=M9DeuohepLob9L1PP2XS4BqlSPM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP35b_3_HKAhUU1WMKHeQZC2YQ6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=elections%20in%20medieval%20sakai&f=false , but I can find few other sources.

Comment: Is there any evidence in your question that you have consulted wikipedia?  I'm far more willing to spend time researching a question if there is some evidence that the OP has done preliminary research.  In point of fact, the history of Sakai looks fascinating, and you're right that the question of urban governance in Sakai at that time is likely to be very interesting.

Comment: How is this question too broad? It is about a single city in a narrow span of time. Certainly an overview of political institutions in such narrow scope isn't "too broad".

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I appreciate you trying to improve my question, but I think you made it rather broader. I'm gonna remove some of the questions you added.

Comment: @BT It was closed as too broad before you edited it to say "during the 500s and 600s". It was too broad because "medieval" is a nebulous concept which span centuries - nothing "narrow" about that whatsoever. Moreover, **"500s and 600s" is nowhere close to being "medieval" in Japanese historiography**. Rather, given the edit (see how helpful sharing your research is), I suspect you'll want to place your question within the **Azuchi–Momoyama period** instead. In any case, you will do better to drop the attitude and take constructive criticism positively rather than rage against the system.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace 's edit would be a better fit, actually, since it specifically targets the autonomous governance of the city, which seems to be what you're actually interested in anyway. Again, there many regime changes in quick succession, so that way you phrased it will encompass all those others.

Comment: @Semaphore I understand you want me to accept your way of viewing things and attempt to conform to them. My philosophy is simply at odds with the philosophy that prompted putting this question on hold. You can read my thoughts on this matter at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Fresheneesz/Don%27t_Destroy . In any case, I'm not in fact interested in why the city was autonomous. Its outside the scope of this question to consider how effective the city was. I'm simply asking what the institutions were during this era.

Comment: Also, the medieval period started in 400 BC according to wikipedia, and 500-700 BC is certainly included therein.

Comment: @BT If Wikipedia claims "the medieval period started in 400 BC", then it is blatantly and moronically wrong. I never said you were interested in "why the city was autonomous" either; I am pointing out that this period of city autonomy you were reading about occurred during the Azuchi-Momoyama era. If you actually wish to learn about history, perhaps you should not disregard my good faith attempt to provide relevant information on a topic clearly outside your forte. But if your goal is to debate your difference of "philosophy" with community rules outside of Meta then I retract my reopen vote.

Comment: I changed Medieval to Azuchi-Momoyama. I'm not disregarding you - you'll notice I took the time to check your information. And I gave you the link to my philosophy so we could stop debating it here. I'd appreciate some assumption of good faith on your part as well if you're asking me to do the same.

Comment: And here are some sources that say you're wrong about when the medieval period: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medieval * http://www.history.com/topics/middle-ages * http://www.britannica.com/event/Middle-Ages * http://people.umass.edu/eng2/per/medieval.html

Comment: @BT I wasn't suggesting you replace "Medieval"; that's totally besides the point. There's a 1000 year gap between the Azuchi Momoyama period, and your "500s and 600s". If you bothered to "check my information" as you claimed you'd notice the contradiction. [I hadn't had any time to check, so I threw out Azuchi–Momoyama period as a ballpark ("I suspect"); turns out Sakai's self rule actually began a few decades earlier though it lasted into it] But the point remains that "Medieval Sakai" absolutely do not refer to the "500s and 600s".

Comment: @BT None of your sources say it began in "400 **BC**". And I *did* specify *"in **Japanese** historiography"*. You'll notice that (f.e.) your first links says : `of or relating to the period of EUROPEAN history from about A.D. 500`. **Japan is not in Europe** - Medieval Japan is conventionally dated to the Kamakura Bakufu's founding in 1185. To be brutally honest, someone who failed to distinguish A.D. from B.C. should perhaps spend more time reading, and less time trying to disprove others.

Comment: @Semaphore Ugghhhhh, you're really throwing me off dude. I made a typo, is that so hard to believe? Jesus christ. I again changed the era to the correct periods. Just because my title was too broad doesn't mean the whole question is too broad. A more appropriate response would have been to modify the title, not put the question on hold. Please stop clogging up the comments here with irrelevant info. To be brutally honest, you're being incredibly unhelpful.

Comment: **It's not about your title.** My comment shave been on the fact that you are asking about the "500s and 600s" which are completely wrong time frames. Again, there is now **a 1000 year gap** between your title and the text of your question. Good job on throwing a fit over the BC part and missing the actual point, which is that Medieval Japan is post **12th century**, not "400" anything.

Comment: @BT Again you proved yourself more eager to debate the philosophy of closing than address points raised. We couldn't just modify your title for you because we can't read your mind, hence it was put on hold for you to clarify yourself. I don't know why you are still whining about that: no one has said it was "too broad" since your first edit. Not that it was ever only about your title to begin with.

Comment: @Semaphore Is it currently still too broad?

Comment: @BT No, it's currently self-contradictory.

Comment: @Semaphore How bout now?

Comment: @BT Now it's nonsensical.

Comment: @Semaphore Please elaborate. I don't see anything that's nonsensical.

Comment: @BT What's to elaborate? I have already explained multiple times that your time frame is totally off.

Comment: @Semaphore I'm asking about the 500s and 600s AD. My time frame is not off. There is nothing obviously nonsensical. If you can't articulate it in english, I have to assume there is nothing nonsensical at this point.

Comment: As I have repeatedly articulated and you repeatedly ignored in favour of your own limited misinformation, you quoted a passage on Sakai in Medieval Japan, and then asked about AD "500s and 600s". That's obviously nonsensical because they are **separated by centuries.**

Comment: @Semaphore You're right, and if you had just pointed it out, I would have realized it much faster. Note also, I didn't add that quote in there, someone else did.

Comment: I pointed it out in my second comment; you simply chose to respond by attempting to disprove me on the dates of Medieval Japan. As it stands this question is answerable and I have one prepared - but I suspect you wouldn't like it.

Comment: @Semaphore Feel free to post an answer, even if I don't like it, perhaps others will

Comment: I don't think you are going to get much of an answer because virtually nothing is none about Sakai, Japan in 500-600 AD.  (http://www.city.sakai.lg.jp/english/visitors/whats/history.html)

Comment: @StevenBurnap That's because Sakai didn't exist back then. The region was basically a giant tomb at the time.

Comment: I might be ignorant, but isn't some form of elected body of government were rather well spread in Japan, especially isolated villages and merchant centers (i.e Hakata vs Fukuoka)? Sakai was prosperous and therefore had more power to power to retain independence, but Japan history is most of the time about struggle and fight of local forces (feudal lords, temples, merchants etc) and very weak centralized government.

Comment: @Greg Not in AD 500. From around the Sengoku period you're right that peasant farmers coalesced into autonomous village units and elected their own leaders. This actually persisted into and expanded during the Edo period despite the imposition of samurai authority.

Comment: @Semaphore Sure, not AD 500. But I would not be surprised if some kind of self governance existed before Sengoku period at many places. Unlike in Europe, where a centralized church dealt with many local administration, in Japan there was no such institution. Local warlords had long tradition to go against whatever central government: I don't think however they cared much about local issues beyond taxes.

Comment: @Greg Ancient Japan used to have a much more strongly centralised monarchy. It is the breakdown of royal governance during the Heian period that allowed the rise of samurai warlords in Medieval Japan. This in turn appointed samurai administrators to oversee/govern the regional manors. The weak central government was really a feature of the subsequent Muromachi shogunate, and was not true generally. The tradition is in fact for local leaders to pledge fealty to the central government in return for official sanction of their holdings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sakai did not exist as a geopolitical entity in your specified timeframe. Therefore, in one sense the "kind of political institution" that existed in 5th-6th century Sakai was of the **non-existent** variety.

The medieval city grew out of the earlier manors of Sakai, which debuted in recorded history as late as 1304. This was on [a court document](http://id.nii.ac.jp/1072/00003826/) assigning ownership to [Saionji Shōko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eifuku-mon_In). In fact, the name of Sakai (`堺`) was first mentioned only in 1045 as `saka-i (さか井)` in a poem of [Fujiwara no Sadayori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujiwara_no_Sadayori). It attained its modern form slightly later in 1081, as recorded in a [diary entry](http://www.ojiri.jp/tamefusakyounikki.html) by Fujiwara no Tamefusa:

> 申剋参住吉社奉幣 戌剋着和泉**堺**之小堂 住吉神主國元依罷神主清経送粮米等
>
> ... stayed the night at Sakai, Izumi ...

Clearly this vastly postdates the question's period of AD "500s and 600s".

---

Alternatively, let us approach the issue examining the area that later became Sakai. The literal answer to the question of "[w]hat government bodies were elected" is **none that we know of.**

Both the city and manor of Sakai straddled the border between [Settsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Settsu_Province) and [Izumi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izumi_Province) under the [ritsuryō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritsury%C5%8D) provincial system. In fact, the name *Sakai* itself is thought to derive from the word "border", `kuni-zakai (国境)`. During the question's timeframe (i.e. late [Kofun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kofun_period) and early [Asuka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asuka_period)), Izumi and Settsu were both part of the proto [Kawachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawachi_Province) province.

Our knowledge of the period is quite limited - the oldest extant history text in Japanese history dates only to AD 720 (though was begun in 681) and is heavily mythological. However, the 9th century [Kujiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kujiki) identifies the province as under the dominion of the Ōshikouchi clan `(凡河内氏)`, who apparently monopolised the position of [Kuni no Miyatsuko `国造`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuni_no_miyatsuko) and claimed descent from Hikokosohori no Mikoto `(彦己曾保理命)`. This makes them cousins to the Yamato royal house.

A Kuni no Miyatsuko were essentially a vassal of the Yamato king. They were appointed from regional lords who had pledged fealty to the Yamato court, and retained a high degree of internal autonomy. The  Ōshikouchi Kuni no Miyatsuko specifically is [thought to be](http://www.nihonjiten.com/data/263200.html) in charge of continental immigrants and diplomacy. Little is known of their domestic political relationship with lesser regional elites, however.

The site of future Sakai appeared to be little more than a graveyard at the time. Since the Koffun period it has hosted the [Mozu Kofun Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozu_kofungun), a series of tombs including the unreasonably oversized [Daisenryo Kofun](http://www.osaka-info.jp/en/facilities/cat17/post_238.html) of (supposedly) the [Nintoku Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Nintoku).

To its south, there *was* a settlement named Suemura `(陶邑)`. As the name implies, Suemura was a major manufacturing centre of [sue ware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sue_ware) (i.e. Japanese pottery). It [seems](http://bunarinn.lolipop.jp/bunarinn.lolipop/tok2-index/11GkinkiAA/kinnki/oosaka2/12/senboku.html) that the operations were centrally managed by the Yamato court, but there are little concrete details. Suemura is believed to have eventually became [Izumigaokacho `(泉ヶ丘町)`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%89%E3%83%B6%E4%B8%98%E7%94%BA) which was merged into Sakai in the 1950s.

There are no indication at all that they "elected" any "government bodies".

---

Ultimately, the question's assumption that "government bodies were elected ... during the 500s and 600s" in Sakai is totally specious. Rather than the 6th century, it seems the question really intended to ask about Sakai in the ***1***6th century, circa the [Azuchi-Momoyama period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuchi%E2%80%93Momoyama_period).

Comment: Hmm, the source I have mentioning that Sakai was a merchant city in the 6th century is here: https://books.google.com/books?id=z8Flb0gZ3ZkC&pg=SA7-PA10&lpg=SA7-PA10&dq=sakai . Also, the source that Steve Burnap mentioned has seems to indicate that Sakai was around at very latest by 646 AD: http://www.city.sakai.lg.jp/english/visitors/whats/history.html . I'm not entirely convinced that there was no government there at the time, but I'm increasingly convinced that you're correct that its not the time period I'm interested in.

Comment: I suspect you're right that the first source actually meant 16th century, I've since found other sources mentioning Gaspar Vilela's description that the city had "consuls like venice" https://books.google.com/books?id=z09oAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA331&lpg=PA331&dq=Gaspar+Vilela+sakai+consuls . I'm finding various sources mentioning this quote about "consuls", which I would say is a strong indication of elected offices, since that's what venice's consuls were. Why don't I ask a new question about the 1500s to 1600s, now that this question is solidly about a different era?

Comment: @BT There was government there, obviously, since we can reasonably assume that it takes the resources of a state to build such a huge burial mound as is purported to be the Nintoku Emperor's. The link SteveBurnap gave spoke of the history of the region that became Sakai; it does not claim that Sakai in the sense of the Medieval city existed.

Comment: @BT I think you'll be better served to forget about timeframes and simply ask something like, "What was the government of Sakai like during its autonomous, reportedly elective period?". And quote those passages that prompted you to ask the question in the first place. To be blunt, of course I am right; and I wished you had listened and put the question in the right period without going through this pointlessly detour to ask about pre-existence Sakai. I get that you shouldn't blindly trust random strangers on the internet, but this concerns a basic and easily verifiable fact.

Comment: If you agree there was a government in Sakai in the 600s AD, what do you mean by "`Sakai did not exist as a geopolitical entity in your specified timeframe`"?

Comment: @BT I didn't agree, I said there was government in the area, not that there was government in "Sakai". There was nothing called "Sakai" and there was no historically significant settlement in the region that could be reasonably considered a precursor to Sakai.  That doesn't mean no government had authority over the land - it was a royal graveyard.

Comment: Gotcha, ok. I'm actually finding enough information in sources to have confidence that you're wrong when you say of elected governing bodies that there were "`none that we know of`". Multiple sources I've found go into evidence that the city had representative councils run by an oligarchy. But thank you for the information you gave in your answer.

Comment: "`of course I am right`" - I think you'd have more luck in your interactions with human beings if you took a few humility pills. Your original handling of my admittedly poorly asked and amateur question was frankly terrible, and I'm glad we've moved past that into more constructive territory. I'd suggest trying a different tactic next time you come across someone asking a bad question in good faith. Please realize that there are people who have nothing more than a high school history background floating around online.

Comment: @BT I interact with people based on what they deserve. In this case, I have no humility for someone who is a stunning and exemplary display of the Dunning-Kruger effect. My "original handling" of your extremely confused question was to helpfully point out that you got the wrong timeframe. It was your attempt to dispute me on the dates of Medieval Japan, like your current attempt to argue (and citing imaginary and invisible "multiple sources") that there was elected bodies in the 500s in Sakai before Sakai ever existed, that is supremely not constructive.

Comment: "`The city didn't even exist`" - I'm now talking about the 1500s. See this is exactly what I'm talking about, you assume the wrong thing, and then make fun of me for your incorrect assumption. There is no such thing as "humility for" someone, its entirely a personal thing - a way you see yourself. Your mention of Dunning-Kruger is incredibly ironic, btw. That you pointed out that my time-frames were inconsistent would have been helpful, except for that the way you pointed out the incorrect timeframe and handled my misunderstanding of your point was the problem.

Comment: @BT And my answer was obviously about the 500s when I said there's no elected bodies we know of, because that's what your question asked. So you're moving the goalpost to call me wrong and then faulting me for assuming that a question about the "500s and 600s" isn't about the 1500s. Right.

Comment: I misunderstood, so I agree saying you were wrong there wasn't correct. Your attitude makes it very difficult to understand and communicate with you. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @BT And your attitude that you are somehow blessed with special insight into a subject you are incredibly ignorant of, and your asinine assumption that any confusion on your part means someone else is wrong, makes it very difficult to help you understand anything.

Comment: I've long since switched to being polite and constructive, whereas you insist on continuing to badger me and call me names like asinine. Something to think about, ey?

Comment: @BT Rather than namecalling, "asinine" is a description of your behaviour, which I do not find "polite" in the slightest. And yes I am quite offended by your repeated attempts to call me wrong.

Comment: You continue to imagine that I'm trying to attack you somehow. Well, I'll leave you to stew then.